# Google Calendar API List Events timeZone parameter

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

While using Google Calendar's Event List API, I encountered an inconsistency in timezone settings. On Google's online API interface, setting 'timeZone' to 'Etc/UTC' correctly returns events in that timezone. However, in my PHP implementation, despite setting 'timeZone' to 'Etc/UTC', events return in the 'Europe/Madrid' timezone, the calendar's default.

In the [Event List documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) I read

> **timeZone**  string  Time zone used in the response. Optional. The default is the time zone of the calendar.

If I use the "try this" in the documentation page, I select 'Etc/UTC' value and the events are returning with the correct timeZone, in this case Etc/UTC.

The problem occurs when I try the same in the google API for PHP

```
$optParams = [
                'syncToken' => $config->syncToken(),
                'timeZone' => 'Etc/UTC'
            ];

$results = $service->events->listEvents($externalCalendar, $optParams);
```

In the response for events I'm receiving them in Europe/Madrid timezone (the calendar timezone), instead of Etc/UTC.

Comment: I would like to confirm your current issue. When I tested your script, I got a returned value including the date time value of `{"dateTime":"2023-06-29T00:00:00Z","timeZone":"UTC"}` like the format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. It seems that this value is the same as the value retrieved by "Try this method". This value is your current issue. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected value?

Comment: @Tanaike this is probably because the default timezone for your calendar is UTC timezone. The response from the "try this method" for me is: start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-06-29T09:00:00Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-06-29T10:00:00Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
   }, as you can see, the dateTime is in UTC and the timeZone value is the calendar timezone configuration, and this is correct. But when I try with my code, the problem occurs: "dateTime":"2023-06-29T09:30:00+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Madrid"

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution.